# Can visual studio code block modifications like vim?

Tags: visual-studio, vim

Is it possible to lock files in visual studio code? Similarly to what you do in vim where you have to press "i" if you want to modify files I'd like to be able to keep the files locked and then press a key that allows me to modify them and then lock them again. Is it possible to do so in visual studio just like in vim?

Comment: You mean modal editing, right? If using *actual* Vim keystrokes and commands would work for you, then consider [Vim for VS Code](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim).

Comment: @filbranden  Yes, I didn't know the name modal editing, sorry. What do you mean Vim keystrokes? I like some of vim commands and I find them useful, at the same time I'd like to navigate the page in the same way I do it with visual studio, does Vim for VS code do that?

Comment: Vim for VS Code makes VS Code start using Vim commands, such as `i` for insert text, `<Esc>` to go back to normal mode, etc. I don't really use VS Code so I can't tell whether it will disable or alter much of the page navigation you like... You should probably give it a try and see if you like it.

Comment: @filbranden yes, I tried it and it works greatly, thank you very much.

Comment: Let me post that as an answer then... Thanks for confirming this was what you were looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for a ["modal editor" interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi#Interface).

If using actual Vim keybindings and commands would work for you, then consider adopting [Vim for VS Code](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim), which emulates most of the Vim UI inside VS Code.

It should give you the best of both worlds.